# If a k-regular graph is 1-factorable, then does it have chromatic index k?

Tags: graph-theory

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#1-factorization) says

> A k-regular graph is 1-factorable if it has chromatic index k.

If I am correct, it means that if a k-regular graph has chromatic index k, then it is 1-factorable.

Although it doesn't imply this, is it true that if a k-regular graph is 1-factorable, then it has chromatic index k? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that a tautology? What are the definitions of "$1$-factorable" and "chromatic index"?

Comment: I don't think it is a tautology. Definitions are in the link.

Comment: Yeah, they're the same.  As Wikipedia states, "In particular, a 1-factor is a perfect matching, and a 1-factorization of a k-regular graph is an edge coloring with k colors.".  So if you have a 1-factorization, you have a $k$ edge-coloring, hence showing that the chromatic index is $k$ (it can't be less than $k$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph that is $1$-factorable. Consider a $1$-factorization of $G$. Since $G$ is $k$-regular the $1$-factorization is an edge coloring of $G$ that uses $k$ colors. Thus $\chi'(G)=k$.

Comment: (Comment deleted, I confused k-factorable, i.e. having a k-factorization, with having a k-factor.)